Laravel, Vue and Apache2 with hot reload with reverse proxy
I´ve been banging my head for over 2 weeks with this and can't make it work for the life of me.
Here's the information:

My site is on a remote server in Digital Ocean, running Ubuntu and apache2.
My frontend is Vue2
My Backend is Laravel 10
Both live on the same server.
I use Auth0 for SSO. (mylogingscreen.mydevsite.com/auth0login?etc)
Certbot for ssl.
Running Laravel Echo using webpack
Using webpack atm, but can change to w/e if needed.

The way the site works currently is by manually compiling the frontend files and copying them to the /public/ folder inside laravel. (Basically, as if it were a production environment). But I need to make it work for front-end dev, so I need hot reload for that.
In other words, I want to go to https://mylogingscreen.mydevsite.com and see my changes live.
I set up my vue.config.js like so:
devServer: {
    allowedHosts: "all",
    client: {
      webSocketURL: 'auto://0.0.0.0:0/ws'
    },

For apache I added this:
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

and my apache site config is like this:
<VirtualHost :80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public
    ServerAlias mylogingscreen.mydevsite.com 

    
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
  
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
    RewriteRule . ws://echo:6001%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
    

    ProxyPass /socket.io http://echo:6001/socket.io
    ProxyPassReverse /socket.io http://echo:6001/socket.io

    <Directory /var/www/laravel>
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mylogingscreen[OR]
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mylogingscreen.mysite.com 
   RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

When I do yarn serve it loads the frontpage fine but any action regarding the backend will just do nothing and reload the frontpage again.
Maybe I should leave webpack for echo and use vite for vue? or use nginx too?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

I'm making some assumptions about your situation, but it sounds like you are going through a lot of pain to keep the front and the back end tightly coupled.  I would recommend a few things depending on your situation:

Consider decoupling the Vue app from the Laravel app.  Options would be moving over to an SPA or SSR using Nuxt.js. (This will almost certainly make things a lot easier and cost less when it comes to both development and deployment of the front end stuff.)

Consider using local development environments unless there is a good reason not to.  It sounds like your using a remote dev server which can complicate things; although most IDEs have helpers/extensions for making this a bit smoother.  Both Laravel and Vue 2 have options for local servers with hot reload that are very easy to configure.

Consider moving from Webpack to Vite. If time is critical for you, which it sounds like it is, this one is a no-brainer.  I have used both extensively and Vite is orders of magnitude more speedy/efficient than Webpack.  Unless there is no way to make the move, in almost all ways: Vite > Webpack.



Thanks for the response, going to clear up a bit


Both apps are running on the same server, but they are on different folders/projects/repos,  etc.


Laravel is pure be with APIs


I would love to use local, but sadly...cant.


I wanted to try that but don't know what would really change on my issue, I think its related to the proxy and how I set things up.


All of it was previously working (hot reload) using docker, and we are moving away from it.

Vue was running ngingx on a container for example.
I tried the same setup with apache and is not working.


Just to clarify, in which environment are you running the dev server (e.g., after running yarn serve) and what is the url being used, and in which environment are you running the browser expecting the hot reloaded content?

my backend is running on apache with laravel, the FE was running by coping the files from the dist folder from the vue project after I use npm run build.  Like a normal production server, but this is no longer needed as the purpose of this remote server is for dev projects.
What I need is that after running yarn serve or npm run dev I can go to mysite.com and be able to see my FE hotreload any changes I make to the FE code.
I managed to do it by using a reverse proxy on apache as per my first post, but when I try to go to something like mysite.com/auth0   All it does is reload mysite.c

It could be a CORS issue - if you don't mind trying nginx, the solution here might be worth trying this.
